# merge two images to simulate clothes shop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, node.js

hope you're doing well

So i a problem to solve, so i need your help please, i want to achieve this result but i have no idea about [video of the result](http://nzaou.dba.ma/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/WhatsApp-Video-2020-08-14-at-17.45.18.mp4).

I have tried canvas with javascript but i don't know how to control the scale of the pattern and i don't know if mix-blend-mode with css will work.

This what i tried to do:

```
let image = new Image();
let pattern = new Image();

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
let cnt = 2;

let inc = document.querySelector('.inc');
let dec = document.querySelector('.dec');

let num = 0.5;


//console.log(ctx)

image.src = './model.png';
pattern.src = './texture.jpg';


console.log(canvas.width)

//console.log(image , pattern)

const go = (inc) => {
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(pattern, "repeat");
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width*.5, image.height*.5);
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width*inc, image.height*inc);
}

image.onload = pattern.onload = function() {if (!--cnt) go(num)};

inc.addEventListener('click' , () => {
    num = num + 0.1
    go(num);
})
```

the result is : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwvKL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Ruben, I've built simple POC to see and test it — so use it to build upon it if fits your needs.

I've used couple of lines to comment what's going on, but that's very easy with native css + alpha images (png's) that someone needs to prepare beforehand

cheers

```js
var x = document.getElementById('pats') // pattern slider
var y = document.getElementById('imgs') // img's slider
var p = document.getElementById('pat') // ref to patter box
var i = document.getElementById('img') // ref to img box

// img array
var a = ["https://i.imgur.com/nPrDAhT.png","https://i.imgur.com/dzw2SdV.png"]

// main function
function update( e ){
  // change size of pattern that is behind
  if( e.target.id == 'pats' ) p.style.backgroundSize = e.target.value + "px"
  // only concept, but do use already existing slider libs or similar
  if( e.target.id == 'imgs' ) i.setAttribute( 'src', a[ e.target.value - 1 ] )
}

// hooking of events onto sliders only
x.addEventListener('input', update );
y.addEventListener('input', update );
```

```css
#scene{
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh
}
#img, #pat{
  position: absolute; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#pat{
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/VuT8Y0G.png)
}
```

```html
<div class="slider-container" style="">
  <div id="x-slider" style="">
    Pattern slider <input id="pats" type="range" min="1.0" max="100.0" value="50.0">
  </div>
  <div id="y-slider" style="">
    Image slider <input id="imgs" type="range" min="1.0" max="2.0" value="1.0">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="scene">
 <div id="pat"> &nbsp; </div>
 <img id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/nPrDAhT.png" src1="https://i.imgur.com/dzw2SdV.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! May God bless u :)

Comment: thank you @rubennzaou glad this helps you :) mark it as solution if happy about it

Comment: somehow it is not working when i tried in my text editor ! i don't know what is wrong